# you dont have extension for debugging kivy.should we find kivy extension in the marketplace?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

[click here for the error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coOWI.png)i tried to run my kivy file in vs code ,but it says that i have no extension to debug kivy .i have kivy installed in my system,also the extension.

i want to clear the error message and to  debug my kv file.i dont know what to do if any one knows why this is happening please help.thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are some extensions for VS code that support some syntax highlighting and possibly auto-complete.  I use one simply named **Kivy**, authored by BattleBas.

You can find this by searching in the Extensions menu on the side bar [Ctrl+Shift+X] or view it here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BattleBas.kivy-vscode

If I may suggest, another popular IDE is PyCharm and there are additional features for Kivy available here:

[kivy github page with help for various IDE addins](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE%27s)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is normal in VS-Code if a .kv file is open when debugging starts.  This will not occur if main.py is open when debugging starts.  If you had the ,kv file open because you literally want to debug that simple file, I can only say that as a kivy/VS-Code user with less than 1 week of experimenting, I don't have any suggestions.  I have found that you can't set breakpoints in a .kv file and there is no dynamic data to watch so it is not clear to me what you expect from a .kv debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug kivy ,do this .you have to link to its main py file and run it.You can't compile kivy file separately. If it has any error it will pop up on the terminal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).